# CakePHP 2.5 Debug MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, ubuntu

I have this code working in Cake 1.3 on the same server, but on the new version of Cake 2.5, when i debug this query i get a blank ouput

app/Model/AppModel

```
class AppModel extends Model 
{

public function connect_to_mssql()
{

    $server = 'SQLSERVER';

    // Connect to MSSQL
    $link = mssql_connect($server, 'user', 'password');
    mssql_query("SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;");
    if (!$link) {
        die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
    }

    $conn = mssql_select_db('database',$link);      

    $client = mssql_query('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM clients');

    $row = mssql_fetch_array($client);
    debug($row);
    die();
}
}
```

Output:

```
/app/Model/AppModel.php (line 54)
```

**EDIT 1**

Just found that the problem it's with debug() function, if i use print_r i get the array, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Debug will only work if the "debug" config variable is set to a number greater than 0.

From the [Cakephp Debugging Manual Page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html):

> To use the debugger, first ensure that Configure::read(‘debug’) is set to a value greater than 0.

Try writing this, either in Core/config.php or in your model just before `debug($row);`

```
Configure::write('debug', 1);
```

Comment: I've debug set to 2, the problem it's with the character encoding from the database, in version 1.3 the debug print the output if there was any problem with the encoding in version 2.5, the ouput comes blank